# CancellationTokenSource.Cancel throws an ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, dispose, race-condition, cancellationtokensource

I have a class that owns a `CancellationTokenSource`.

```
public class GrabboxCell : UICollectionViewCell
{
    CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource ();

    // ...
}
```

I'm using current token to start some long-running operations.

My object also needs to support “recycling”. Think reincarnation. All long-running operations started during previous life must be cancelled.

In this case I call `Cancel` and `Dispose` on the source, and issue a new token source:

```
void CancelToken (bool createNew)
{
    _tokenSource.Cancel ();
    _tokenSource.Dispose ();
    _tokenSource = null;

    if (createNew) {
        _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource ();
    }
}
```

I call this method in two places: when I want the token to expire and when this class is disposed.

```
public override void PrepareForReuse ()
{
    CancelToken (true);
    base.PrepareForReuse ();
}

protected override void Dispose (bool disposing)
{
    CancelToken (false);
    base.Dispose (disposing);
}
```

Sometimes I'm getting an `ObjectDisposedException` when calling `_tokenSource.Cancel ()` from my `Dispose` method. Documentation says:

> All public and protected members of `CancellationTokenRegistration` are thread-safe and may be used concurrently from multiple threads, with the exception of `Dispose`, which must only be used when all other operations on the `CancellationTokenRegistration` have completed.

I'm not sure what to do at this moment. Wrap `CancelToken` in a `lock`?
Where exactly does the race condition happen and how to mitigate it?

I know for sure that `PrepareForReuse` is *always* called on the same thread, but `Dispose` may be called on a different one.

If this is of any use, I'm running Mono and not .NET Framework but I'm pretty sure they should have the same semantics regarding cancellation tokens.

Comment: Interestingly, I just found this: [`SafeCancellationTokenSource`](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Infrastructure/SafeCancellationTokenSource.cs).

Comment: `I need current token to expire` What does it mean?

Comment: @Hamlet: I want the token previously returned by `_tokenSource.Token` to be cancelled.

Comment: @Hamlet I made an edit, is it clear now?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This isn't really interesting but I wrapped `Cancel` and `Dispose` into a try-catch that swallows `ObjectDisposedException` and haven't had problems since.

Answer (score 2):

The operations being thread safe (individually) does not imply that your sequence of operations are executed at once. More specifically, since `PrepareForReuse` could run in a different thread as `Dispose`, then what could happen is that this:

```
_tokenSource.Cancel ();
_tokenSource.Dispose ();
```

is executed in one thread, then there is a Context Switch between threads before executing `_tokenSource = null;` and then another thread tries to run again the `_tokenSource.Cancel ()`. But the tokenSource was disposed of already and not regenerated, since the first thread did not reach the last block of code of the cancel:

```
_tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource ();
```

I would not be surprised either if you get from time to time a `NullPointerException`, if the context switch happened just after `_tokenSource = null;` instead of before as I explained (it is also possible).

To solve this problem I would lock your `Cancel` method so that the threads cannot run any part of the method before the other was finished.

Also, to protect for the `NullPointerException`, which can only happen if your method `Dispose` is called before `PrepareForReuse`, you can use the [*Null-Conditional Operator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-).